# Why epoll_wait(), get returned and TCP connect time out in 5s~10s

Tags: linux, tcp, network-programming, tcpclient, epoll

I create a non-blocking socket, and then use the `epoll` to manange the socket. I do not set a timeout on `epoll_wait`. But I find that the `epoll` returned in 5s to 10s, then I check with the `getsockopt` on `SO_ERROR`, the connect find to be timed out. Why time out in so short time?

I try to use tools to cap the TCP packages. The scenario is like this:

When my client send a `SYN` in order to connect to the server. But the server cannot send back the `ACK` in 5s to 10s. Then the `epoll_wait` return. and check with the `SO_ERROR`. I get a `EIMTEDOUT`.

I just cannot understand why the timeout time is so short in 5s to 10s. Is the problem of my client or is the `epoll`?

Comment: +1 - 5-10 secs is indeed very short for a connect timeout.  If the link contained a dial-up modem, for example, the connect would always fail with such a short timeout.  I would like to know why this happens as well.

Comment: I don't knwo why. I just use the libev. the description above is exactly what the libev do in C++. I just find the libev return ETIMEDOUT in so short time.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471577/linux-tcp-connect-failure-with-etimedout) recently See the accepted answer which explains how the TCP connect timeout value is calculated by the linux kernel.. If you happen to have the client/server on the same machine its quite likely to have shorter timeout values. If you expect server to take longer than that to accept a connection you might want to set the timeout value yourself explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. I got over it. As your question, the TCP timeout value is calculated dynamically by the kernel.